# Name for variant of Pascal's triangle with different initial conditions

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, binomial-coefficients

I ran into an interesting variant of Pascal's triangle in generating an expression for an alternating sum of falling factorials

$$
\sum_{i=0}^{a} (-1)^i (i)_k = k! T(a, k)
$$

where $T(a, k)$ satisfies the basic binomial recurrence but with different initial conditions

$$
\begin{align}
T(a, k) &= T(a-1, k) + T(a-1, k-1) \\
T(a, a) &= 1 \\
T(a, 0) &= (1 + (-1)^a)/2 \\
\end{align}
$$

which looks like

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 3 & 6 & 7 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 3 & 9 & 13 & 11 & 5 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Is there a generic name for the different sequences satisfying this recurrence or for these variants of Pascal's triangle in general?

Comment: See [A059260](https://oeis.org/A059260) in OEIS.